# Struct with template variables in C++

Tags: c++, class, templates, struct

I'm playing around with templates. I'm not trying to reinvent the std::vector, I'm trying to get a grasp of templateting in C++.

Can I do the following?

```
template <typename T>
typedef struct{
  size_t x;
  T *ary;
}array;
```

What I'm trying to do is a basic templated version of:

```
typedef struct{
  size_t x;
  int *ary;
}iArray;
```

It looks like it's working if I use a class instead of struct, so is it not possible with typedef structs?

Answer (score 176, accepted):

The problem is you can't template a typedef, also there is no need to typedef structs in C++.

The following will do what you need

```
template <typename T> 
struct array { 
  size_t x; 
  T *ary; 
};
```

Comment: +1 for explaining the difference between your code and @monkeyking's.

Comment: How do you create a constructor with an initializer list for the `struct` if you don't `typedef` it? Make a class instead? [One answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64750247/13132315) basically creates aliases for each type `T`, which isn't ideal.

Comment: @Breno: Can you ask that in a new question. I haven't written C++ code in 15 or more years now, sorry.

Answer (score 19):

```
template <typename T>
struct array {
  size_t x;
  T *ary;
};
```

Answer (score 9):

You don't need to do an explicit `typedef` for classes and structs. What do you need the `typedef` for? Further, the `typedef` after a `template<...>` is syntactically wrong. Simply use:

```
template <class T>
struct array {
  size_t x;
  T *ary;
} ;
```

Comment: Hm, did you mean to put that after struct?

Answer (score 5):

You can template a struct as well as a class. However you can't template a typedef. So `template<typename T> struct array {...};` works, but `template<typename T> typedef struct {...} array;` does not. Note that there is no need for the typedef trick in C++ (you can use structs without the `struct` modifier just fine in C++).

Answer (score 4):

The Standard says (at 14/3. For the non-standard folks, the names following a class definition body (or the type in a declaration in general) are "declarators")

> In a template-declaration, explicit specialization, or explicit instantiation the init-declarator-list in the dec-laration shall contain at most one declarator. When such a declaration is used to declare a class template, no declarator is permitted.

Do it like Andrey shows.

Answer (score 3):

The syntax is wrong. The `typedef` should be removed.

Answer (score 3):

From the other answers, the problem is that you're templating a typedef. The only "way" to do this is to use a templated class; ie, basic template metaprogramming.

```
template<class T> class vector_Typedefs {
    /*typedef*/ struct array { //The typedef isn't necessary
        size_t x; 
        T *ary; 
    }; 

    //Any other templated typedefs you need. Think of the templated class like something
    // between a function and namespace.
}

//An advantage is:
template<> class vector_Typedefs<bool>
{
    struct array {
        //Special behavior for the binary array
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Looks like @monkeyking is trying it to make it more obvious code as shown below

```
template <typename T> 
struct Array { 
  size_t x; 
  T *ary; 
};

typedef Array<int> iArray;
typedef Array<float> fArray;
```