# struct template using struct template

Tags: c++, templates, struct, linked-list

I am facing a problem implementing a templated struct in another templated struct.

Basically this works:

```
template<typename T>
struct ListElement {
    T Value;
    struct ListElement<T>* Next;
};

template<typename M>
struct List {
    struct ListElement<M>* ContainedElements;
};
```

But what I really want is an implementation like that:

```
template<typename T>
struct ListElement {
    T Value;
    struct ListElement<T>* Next;
};

template<typename M>
typedef struct ListElement<M>* List;
```

The thing is that you can not use typedef with templates. Any workaroud to write `struct List<Anytype>` instead of struct ListElementPointer*?

PS: It is a school project by the way. Using standard vector or list classes is not allowed and I do not want to type new definitions for every type I use...classes are not allowed as well :-/

Comment: what do you mean by "you can not use typedef with templates". What error, or problem do you encounter ?

Comment: @StephaneRolland it gives syntax errors as it is not allowed. It was discussed in other topics [[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2448242/struct-with-template-variables-in-c)]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are able to use C++11, you can use the following alias declaration:

```
template<typename M>
using List = ListElement<M>*;
```

Comment: Thanks. It should be added that it was added as "alias declarations" in C++11.